# Stockfish on Android Question

Tags: engines, stockfish

I recently downloaded Stockfish 10 on my android phone and after unzipping the rar file, there were three separate engine binaries and I am wondering which one would be the strongest one to use.  The three that were in the folder are stockfish-10-arm64-pgo, stockfish-10arm64v8, and stockfish-10armv7.  Which one of these binaries would be the strongest one to use?

Comment: is this question solved?

Answer (score 2):

Android 32 bits? stockfish-10armv7

Android 64 bits? stockfish-10arm64v8 and stockfish-10-arm64-pgo

stockfish-10-arm64-pgo is faster but also with larger file